# Orbiting Earth before heading to Moon

Tags: orbital-mechanics, apollo-program, astrodynamics

Each of the lunar Apollo missions (Apollo 8-17) entered Earth orbit immediately after launch. Each mission then left Earth after a few orbits by burning the S-IVB engine, and headed off to the Moon. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_program#Lunar_mission_profile)

The wikpedia page says orbiting Earth was necessary "to verify readiness of spacecraft systems", but I'm curious how this affected fuel requirements and other aspects of navigation. Would heading toward the Moon directly from the launch pad have required more or less fuel? If orbiting earth first is less efficient, how much extra fuel does it require over leaving directly?

Comment: In addition to [Russell's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/13538/415), note that in the event of a booster malfunction, at any point [between Mode III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_abort_modes#Details) and TLI, Earth orbit insertion was possible. Any kind of abort prior to TLI meant you lost the entire Moon mission (not even like Apollo 13 which at least rounded the Moon and got some snapshots of it), but going into an Earth parking orbit greatly lengthened the window where problems could be dealt with. (Compare Apollo 12: without parking orbit, that might have been an abort.)

Answer (score 24):

Going from Earth's surface direct to Moon orbit without stopping in LEO would offer negligible savings -- depending on your assumptions, maybe 20 m/s worth of ∆v (and 2-3 hours worth of consumables).<sup>1</sup>

According to [Apollo By The Numbers](http://georgetyson.com/files/apollostatistics.pdf) and [Bob Braeunig's simulations](http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/saturnV.htm), the ∆v budget for launch to orbit plus trans-lunar injection for the Apollo missions totalled about 12250 m/s, so any difference would be far less than 1% of the fuel budget.

---

1. Assuming ascent to circular orbit at the [Kármán line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) in either case, then in the first case doing two [Hohmann transfers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit#Calculation), from Kármán line to 160km parking orbit then from parking orbit to lunar altitude; and in the second case a single Hohmann transfer from Kármán line to lunar altitude. The Apollo missions did a faster trajectory than Hohmann (saving 2 days travel time each way) but the difference between the parking orbit and non-stop versions is probably very similar.

Comment: A Hohmann orbit from Earth to LEO isn't an option.

Comment: But *orbital-velocity-at-Earth-radius* minus *Earth-surface-velocity* is the same in both the direct-to-moon and LEO-parking-orbit cases, so it should work out the same; imagine a frictionless spherical <strike>cow</strike> planet with no atmosphere and a rocket skating up to orbital velocity on the surface.

Comment: You try to do a horizontal take off at earth's surface and it will go badly. Again, achieving orbital velocity on earth's surface isn't in the picture. The major horizontal burn is done above earth's atmosphere. For a brief time virtually all trajectories are a few hundred kilometers above the earth moving horizontally at 7.7 km/s.

Comment: If I understand what you're getting at, then the 100 m/s figure would be an upper bound on the difference?

Comment: The $\Delta v$ requirements are essentially covering three components: getting to orbital altitude, getting to orbital speed, and overcoming atmospheric drag. Losses to drag are about the same for any target orbit because that part of the flight is essentially the same for any launch. Getting to orbit altitude and speed can be broken into separate manoeuvres without changing the overall $\Delta v$ since it is just a matter of imparting energy at the right time and the forces are all conservative. _So, there isn't really a difference._

Comment: Hohmann transfer from 100km Kármán line to 160km Apollo parking orbit is 35 m/s ∆v, so there is still a difference; net savings of about 70m/s for the nonstop flight. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Whoops, spreadsheet error. Difference is 20m/s, not 70, if we use the K-line as the reference altitude.

Comment: Why is it necessary to establish an orbit at 100km? Would it be possible to never gain any horizontal velocity, and accelerate straight up from Earth to Lunar orbit?

Comment: @SamHallerman it is possible, but very ineffective as you fight the gravity all the way up. (I did it in Kerbal Space Program for example, needed a big rocket)

Comment: @SamHallerman [Space isn't like that.](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/)

Comment: @SamHallerman the problem with space isn't getting high enough, it's getting *fast* enough. Picture one of those coin funnel things where you put a coin in the slot and it spirals faster and faster as it rolls into the middle. That's what a gravity well is like. If your coin could somehow speed up, it would spiral up out of the funnel instead of down into it. The Apollo craft did the same thing: they sped up to climb out of the Earth's gravity, until they got close enough to the Moon to fall into its (rather smaller) gravity well.

Comment: @SamHallerman If you are interested in space orbit mechanics, play Kerbal Space Program (and kill a large number of Kerbals).  The physics is far from perfect, but it is good enough.  The experience of getting a space ship to orbit the Mun (the Moon), then return to Kerbal (Earth), in KSP is a real education; and, "cheating" by "not designing everything yourself" is encouraged (copy copy copy!), as the problem-space is rich enough that you need all the help you can get.

Comment: Going straight to the moon would have been easier but would have left a lot less room to deal with problems.  The thing is their rocket was LH2/LOX--it was subject to boil-off.

Comment: @lorenpechtel Your comment makes no sense. Spending time in a parking orbit means more boil off than an immediate insertion.

Comment: Okay, starting at a 100 km altitude orbit is a more realistic than assuming an orbit at earth's surface. Then going up to a 160 km parking orbit before departing for TLI would cost an extra 20 meters/second as you say. About half a percent.  But even starting at a 100 km orbit is a stretch. See the Townsend quote in my answer. Most trajectories achieve orbital velocity at a few hundred kilometers altitude. But I'll undo my down vote since you say "negligible savings".

Comment: Yeah, I'm on the fence about deleting.

Answer (score 11):

> The wikpedia page says orbiting Earth was necessary "to verify readiness of spacecraft systems", but I'm curious how this affected fuel requirements and other aspects of navigation.

The use of a parking orbit most likely **saved** fuel compared to a direct translunar insertion. A direct insertion into a translunar trajectory would have saved a tiny amount of fuel compared to that need by adding a parking orbit if everything went perfectly. However, nothing ever works perfectly. Rocket thrust varies, and navigation sensors are imperfect. Launch in the Apollo era was largely a [dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) process; there was no such thing as GPS in the Apollo era.

This meant that navigation errors built up during launch. A launch directly into a translunar trajectory would have meant correcting for those errors and the injection error after the launch+injection. This would have more than offset the tiny extra cost of placing the vehicle into a parking orbit before undergoing the translunar injection. With a parking orbit, most of the launch errors were corrected for by the translunar injection burn. Correction burns were still needed, but these were much smaller than those that would have been needed for a direct launch.

Much more importantly, the use of a parking orbit made the missions possible. A direct translunar insertion launch would have required an instantaneous launch window. The launch would have had to have been delayed by a day (or perhaps by several months) if something went wrong during the countdown in the case of a direct insertion into a translunar trajectory. Mission planners deemed that a 2.5 hour launch window was the minimum needed to have a reasonable chance of success. This alone ruled out the possibility of a launch directly into a translunar trajectory.

Something did indeed go wrong during the countdown in two of the Apollo missions. Apollo 14 launched 40 minutes late due to weather problems, and Apollo 17 launched 2 hours and 40 minutes late due to an automatic cutoff at the T-30 second mark.

That NASA used the parking orbit as a means for verifying the readiness of spacecraft systems for the continuation of the mission was an added benefit of using a parking orbit. This was not the primary driver. The primary driver was that the use of a parking orbit made the missions feasible.

Comment: There was no GPS in the Apollo era, but there were the [Transit satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_(satellite)) , a much simpler satellite navigation system.

Comment: @Uwe, Transit couldn't be used to locate a spacecraft.  It used a combination of time, Doppler shift, and pattern of change in Doppler shift to determine the receiver location.  This only works well when the receiver is stationary or nearly so: submarines get good accuracy, ships get reasonable accuracy, airplanes get poor accuracy, and Apollo could only tell that it was somewhere in the vicinity of Earth.

Comment: @Mark Yes it is true, Transit was not useful for any spacecraft. If a submarine surfaced for only a short time to catch a single overflight of Transit, the submarine did not know if it was left or right of the Transit ground track. Two overflights were needed to exclude the wrong location.

Answer (score 6):

Achieving orbital velocity on earth's surface is not practical due to earth's atmosphere. First a ship must get above the atmosphere and then achieve orbital velocity.

Once altitude is gained, the most efficient way to achieve orbital velocity is by a horizontal burn. You could do the major burn along a non zero flight path angle but then the vertical component of the thrust suffers gravity loss.

[image]

Typically, the first part of a space ship's trajectory is nearly vertical but then leans to the east to give the thrust vector a bigger horizontal component as the atmosphere gets thinner.

When the ship's above the atmosphere it does the major burn and is traveling at a near zero flight path angle (In other words, horizontally).

So a direct insertion to lunar orbit would be doing burn to achieve 10.9 km/s horizontal velocity when above the atmosphere. But at sometime during this burn, the ship will be traveling at a horizontal velocity of 7.8 km/s. At this point I would say the ship is in orbit. After achieving orbital velocity the ship could keep on firing to achieve another 3.1 km/s for Trans Lunar Insertion (TLI).

Or it could cut off the engines after achieving orbital velocity and the do the remaining 3.1 km/s TLI burn later. What is the difference is delta V? Zero.

From John Schilling's [launch simulator methodology pdf](http://www.silverbirdastronautics.com/LaunchMethodology.pdf):

> The Townsend technique begins by assuming that all space launches
>   consist of a direct ascent to a low circular parking orbit, followed
>   by a series of on-orbit maneuvers to the final destination orbit. In
>   fact, many launch vehicles fly only a direct-ascent trajectory, even
>   to a high or non- circular orbit. **However, an observation of these
>   trajectories almost invariably finds the launch vehicle, at an
>   altitude of a few hundred kilometers, accelerating almost horizontally
>   through the local circular orbit velocity.** One may simplify the
>   problem by treating this as an instantaneous "parking orbit", reached
>   by direct ascent, and with all subsequent powered flight treated as an
>   "on-orbit maneuver".

Emphasis added mine.

Again, virtually all trajectories are in low earth orbit for a time. Sometimes very briefly, some times in an extended parking orbit.